# Python class % operator overloading

Tags: python, format, magic-methods

I have a set of functions that calculate different numeric characteristics (in example named `calculate`) but some of them might not be calculate properly. After calculation result will be print in graphic user interface with string formatting. So I would like to return an object of special class that can be formatted as float but return constant value e.g. N/A (`_WrongCalculationError`). Is there any magic method in Python to do so using **oldstyle formatting**?

```
class _WrongCalculationError(object):
    def __??????__(self):
        return "N/A"

WrongCalculationError = _WrongCalculationError()

def calculate(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return WrongCalculationError
    else:
        return x/y

 def main(*args):
     print("Calculation result is: %.3f" % calculate(args[0], args[1])
```

I read about `__format__` method but I would not like to use new-style formatting because in my point of view it's too complicated and hard to read.

Comment: @JonClements because during formatting exception will be raise (str is not float and can't be format)

Comment: What do you actually want the output to look like, when the result is a WrongCalculationError?

Comment: `"Calculation result is {0:.3f}".format(calculate(args[0], args[1]))`. If you're using Python 2.7, you can drop the 0: `{:.3f}`. It's nearly identical to the old-style formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** You should `raise` (not `return`) errors, and they should inherit from `Exception`:

```
class WrongCalculationError(Exception):
    pass

def calculate(x, y):
    if x == y:
        raise WrongCalculationError
    return x / y
```

Then you can handle them like:

```
try:
    print("Calculation result is: %.3f" % calculate(args[0], args[1]))
except WrongCalculationError:
    print("Oops!")
```

---

**Long answer:** The "magic methods" for *modulo* `%` are `__mod__`, `__rmod__` and `__imod__`:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        print "foo:", other


>>> t = Test()
>>> t % "bar"
foo: bar
```

However, this is really just a syntax hack; it only *looks a bit like* C-style string formatting. If you want to pass your custom object as an `value` to `%` (i.e. on the right-hand side) this will not work; `__rmod__` is **not** the same:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def __rmod__(self, other):
        raise Exception


>>> t = Test()
>>> "bar %s" % t
'bar <__main__.Test object at 0x030A0950>'
>>> "bar %f" % t

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    "bar %f" % t
TypeError: float argument required, not Test
```

Note that:

1. `__rmod__` is never called; and
2. `TypeError` occurs on a `'%f'` conversion specification.

You can't customise C-style string formatting; the only exception is that `'%s'` will call `__str__`, which you can implement, but you certainly can't give a non-`float` as a value for `'%f'`. By comparison, you can totally mess around with `str.format`:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def __format__(self, spec):
        return "hello!"


>>> "{0:03f}".format(Test())
'hello!'
```

**Edit**: As Martijn points out in the comments you *could* implement `__float__` to provide a value to `'%f'`, but this *has to return a float*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about exception but in my case there is can be once more situation when characteristic should not be added to GUI at all and in this case I raise exception that characteristic not suitable. Using % operation really can reduce code and it's just interesting is there such syntax sugar to do that. I think I could do what I want using `__mod__` method.

Comment: @Alexei you can't, for the reason I've outlined - `"%s" % obj` *looks like* `obj.__rmod__("%s")`, but **isn't**. You should get to grips with `str.format`. You can't customise an object's formatting for e.g. `%f`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've just try `__mod__` hack and it's really look like hack). Apparently, using exception is the best solution here.

Comment: Since `%f` is used, the exception could implement `__float__`; but that can *only* return a float value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good point, I hadn't thought of that, but I don't know what the OP had in mind for the output in the error case.

Comment: The notion that `str.format()` is too complicated is a little.. stubborn, especially when they can handle their use case perfectly with that. Oh well.